# I am using codeigniter with bootstrap and I keep getting errors on mixing files, how do I correct this errors? here is my code snippet

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

```
public function __construc1nv3ntiph('rs/cloudfiles.php');

  $ci =& get_instance();
  $ci->config->load('cloudfiles');
  $this->user = $ci->config->item('cf_user');
  $this->api_key = $ci->config->item('cf_api_key');
```

this is the error i get on the `public function _Construc1nv3tiph()`
Description 
Resource Path Location Type **syntax error**,

> unexpected
>   ''rs/cloudfiles.php'' Cloudfiles.php  /1nv3ntiph/1nv3ntiph/application/libraries  line
>   13    PHP Syntax Error

Comment: I guess you are trying to define a `function`?

Comment: @Sougata yes I am trying to define a constructor

Comment: Why not simply `public function __construct($f = 'rs/cloudfiles.php') { ... }`?

Comment: thank you, that helped. it was an eclipse build error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are passing parameter to cnstructor is wrong,

```
public function __construc1nv3ntiph('rs/cloudfiles.php');
```

do it like this

```
public function __construc1nv3ntiph($a = "rs/cloudfiles.php");
```

Also take care about other lines of your code, if needed, enclose them inside a function.

Comment: still giving the same error, I am working on Eclipse.. could that be the cause?

Comment: It works well now.. it was a build error from eclipse

Comment: oh ok ok.. Glad i could help you:)